can only use the Fetch Metadata Request Headers(Sec-Fetch-*) in https?
I wanna check User Entrance or not in http

when enter address 'http://my-proj.com' on chrome
click to bookmark shortcut on chrome
etc ...

My project looks like this
A: Staff(browser) ---> foo-server ---> bar-server
B: (Redirected by another server) ---> foo-server ---> API G/W
I want to seperate case A and B,
so I found this https://www.w3.org/TR/fetch-metadata/
as above link, I understand to seperate that by using Sec-Fetch-User = '?1', Sec-Fetch-Site = 'None' in request headers
but my call hasn't Sec-Fetch-*
When I try to above of 1 or 2,
my request headers:
Accept:
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:
ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection:
keep-alive
Cookie:
_ga_0YMR1NFF44=GS1.1.1711615257.1.0.1711615259.58.0.0; _ga_C03MHTENKC=GS1.1.1711938748.2.1.1711939166.60.0.0; _ga_VW3DNKPS2F=GS1.1.1712033578.4.1.1712033592.46.0.0; _ga_X7WFS6WM9P=GS1.1.1712033578.6.1.1712033592.0.0.0; _ga_DRE7DY9MCY=GS1.1.1712539384.16.1.1712539394.0.0.0; _ga_Z6BSK4LPFT=GS1.1.1712539391.19.0.1712539394.57.0.0; _ga_1M3XSVLT9N=GS1.1.1712539394.12.1.1712539415.39.0.0; _gid=GA1.2.1425931462.1712562694; _ga=GA1.2.237546209.1711594085; _ga_NTZC77ZJH8=GS1.1.1712627788.11.1.1712629391.0.0.0; 
Host:
my-proj.com:51111
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:
1
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

however, I got hint in other request headers of "HTTPS"
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Google Chrome";v="123", "Not:A-Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="123"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
document
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site:
none
Sec-Fetch-User:
?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:
1
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

Sec-Fetch-* headers, why only exists in HTTPS headers, not supported in HTTP?

Oddly, Answer myself...
I found also can read Sec-Fetch headers at http://localhost, http://127.0.0.1
Maybe Sec-Fetch headers is included about safety origin, like HTTPS, localhost, etc ...
If my answer is collect or wrong, plz comment me :'-(

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
